# A method to retrieve a carabiner

Tags: rock-climbing, top-roping, carabiners

**I saw this a few times, years ago**

I met some guys who were top roping next to us in Jackson Falls, IL 25 years ago who showed us a method of retrieving your top carabiner(s) when you were done top roping.

They attached the rope to the 'biner in a strange way AND I seem to remember some para-cord being used to pull on and the 'biner would just 'unsnap' from the anchor and come down, on the rope maybe?

Does someone recognize what I'm describing?

I also recall the method as being a bit unsafe and never used it, therefore my imprecise description of the practice.

Comment: Were they top roping off a big tree or boulder? Texas rope trick won't work when using hanger anchors.

Comment: Hanger anchors.

Comment: Did they need to do anything before retrieving it? Or were they able to top rope and then immediately retrieve the rope without modification?

Answer (score 5):

I believe that what you are referring to is called the ["Texas Rope Trick"](http://www.rockclimbing.com/cgi-bin/forum/gforum.cgi?post=1657055;). I hope that it's obvious that this is an incredibly risky idea and that you are better off just leaving the carabiner.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a collection of retrieval methods, some including carabiners.
Perhaps looking through here will job your memory.

http://dyeclan.com/outdoors101/canyoneering101/?page=rigging-a-retrievable-rope

Comment: Unless I misunderstood the original question, they were top roping off it first? These look like rappel+retrieve methods which may not match OP's story

Answer (score 1):

You might be referring to this.
The gray line would be the paracord / accessory cord and the blue line would be the rope.

[image: You might be referring to this]

I guess this might not be it since you never want to thread your rope directly through an anchor.